# Why do my attribute table headings keep changing?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I am working on a project which previously had no issues. I recently went in to create another layer and when I created the vector layer the headings that I had given to the entries all changed to things like "Action" "_1" "_2" etc. No matter how many times I tried to add in new columns they would continue to change similar to this pattern. In addition, my previously created layers now seem to be messed up as well. All the data entered are changed to symbols rather than numbers and text.

Any suggestions on what could be the cause or the solution?

[image: Screenshot of items entered in for layer attributes]

[image: Once I hit 'Ok' this is what happens to my attribute table]

[image: This is what a previously created layer now looks like. I don't have a screengrab of the original entered data.]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the second box of your first picture (file encoding) you'll see that your encoding is set to UTF-32BE if you didn't set it that way on purpose (because you need to use this specific encoding) that's probably what is causing your problem, try to set it to UTF-8 or system and try again

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly it!